# MYSQL order by field condition in case of tie

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, ranking-functions

I have a mysql table like this

```
Brand     Count
TOYOTA     20
HONDA      50
BMW        5
PORSCHE    10
HYUNDAI    10
MAZDA      10
```

I want to sort the table based on the COUNT column in Descending and in-case of tie I want to order the BRAND column to PORSCHE, BMW, HONDA, TOYOTA, MAZDA, HYUNDAI so the result will be like below:

```
Brand     Count
HONDA      50
TOYOTA     20
PORSCHE    10
BMW        10
HYUNDAI    10
MAZDA      5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field) for custom ordering

```
ORDER BY `Count` DESC, 
         FIELD(BRAND, 'PORSCHE', 'BMW', 'HONDA', 'TOYOTA', 'MAZDA', 'HYUNDAI')
```